# Logstash ping (or similar) to report its health to Amazon ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash

I have an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer which has a health checker. It attempts to connect to my Logstash instance running on some_ec2_instance:5000.

The ELB health check attempts to open a tcp connection at some_ec2_instance:5000. However, it never passes this health test. I can manually connect to the the ec2 instance and check that Logstash is running and it is indeed operational. I can also `telnet localhost 5000` into it without any problems.

In addition my security group allows input/outputs on port 5000 so I don't think that is a problem.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to enable the ELB to pass the health check? is there a `/ping` path or a plugin which will enable access to such path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running elasticsearch and logstash on the same hosts, open port **9200** to your ELB and use a http health check on that port.

[Running ELB health checks against port 5000 (logstash itself) overwhelms the port](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1598).

Comment: As per docs, http healthcheck is not fully reliable.
`The HTTP protocol doesn’t deal well with long running requests. This plugin will either return a 429 (busy) error when Logstash is backlogged, or it will time out the request.`